# Troubleshooting : Raspberry Pi3 (Jessie) as a WiFi Hotspot

Tags: raspbian, wifi, hotspot

System : Raspberry Pi 3, Raspbian Jessie

My network : 192.4.13.XX Windows 2012 DHCP range from 192.4.13.20 to 192.4.13.179

Gateway 192.4.13.247

Internal DNS Server 192.4.13.212

RaspBerry ETH0 IP : 192.4.13.217

RaspBerry WLAN0 IP : 192.4.13.218

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:32:c0:49
          inet adr:192.4.13.217  Bcast:192.4.13.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::b09b:d79e:ab83:4de4/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:132531 errors:0 dropped:1073 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000
          RX bytes:21295634 (20.3 MiB)  TX bytes:2280843 (2.1 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8775 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8775 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1
          RX bytes:1287355 (1.2 MiB)  TX bytes:1287355 (1.2 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:67:95:1c
          inet adr:192.4.13.218  Bcast:192.4.13.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: fe80::fe74:a710:4df1:d04d/64 Scope:Lien
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14537 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000
          RX bytes:979736 (956.7 KiB)  TX bytes:27797 (27.1 KiB)
```

DNSMASQ.conf

```
    interface=wlan0      # Use interface wlan0
listen-address=192.4.13.217 # Explicitly specify the address to listen on
bind-interfaces      # Bind to the interface to make sure we aren't sending things elsewhere
server=192.4.13.212       # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS
domain-needed        # Don't forward short names
bogus-priv           # Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.
dhcp-range=192.4.13.190,192.4.13.199,12h # Assign IP addresses between 192.4.13.190 and 192.4.13.199 with a 12 hour lease time
```

hostapd.conf

```
# This is the name of the WiFi interface we configured above
interface=wlan0

# Use the nl80211 driver with the brcmfmac driver
driver=nl80211

# This is the name of the network
ssid=MY-SSID

# Use the 2.4GHz band
hw_mode=g

# Use channel 6
channel=6

# Enable 802.11n
ieee80211n=1

# Enable WMM
wmm_enabled=1

# Enable 40MHz channels with 20ns guard interval
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]

# Accept all MAC addresses
macaddr_acl=0

# Use WPA authentication
auth_algs=1

# Use WPA2
wpa=2

# The network passphrase
wpa_passphrase=my-wifi-password

# Use AES, instead of TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
```

interface

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

dhcpcd.conf

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by default.
#option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname

interface wlan0
static routers=192.4.13.247
static domain_name_servers=192.4.13.212
static ip_address=192.4.13.218/24
static domain_search=

interface eth0
static routers=192.4.13.247
static domain_name_servers=192.4.13.212
static ip_address=192.4.13.217/24
static domain_search=
```

I see the wifi network.

I can connect to the wifi network

I receive an IP in the right range

But I can't have access to internet nor the internal network (shared drives,...)

What I have done wrong ?

Comment: Are you using public IP? And you have defined the same subnet on both the eth0 and wlan0 interface,  and I cant see any bridging of those.